# cytoscape: How to set a rectangle or ellipse other than square layout

Tags: layout, cytoscape

To layout a network in cytoscape, the layout appearance is always a square. If I need to arrange the layout with a ellipse or rectangle appearance, I have to move the nodes manually. For exampke, the "yFiles Organic Layout" produces a layout in a round appearance. How can I change the default appearance to rectangle or ellipse?

Thank you!
Pengcheng Yang

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a way to do that.  It's specific to each layout algorithm how it handles the boundary.  There will be a new layout algorithm that allows you to associate nodes to a drawn annotation, but it's not released yet (hopefully very soon).

-- scooter